# OpenGL Textures (from .png files) not displaying correctly on low-end phone

Tags: android, graphics, resources, png, scaling

**The problem**

I have an atlast of various backgrounds which (in the **HDPI** folder) is 5760 x 459 in size. Originally, the file size was 1.5MB.

I've tested this on a few devices, a Nexus 10 tablet (which gets the bigger version of the file from the XHDPI folder), a generic tablet (using MDPI), a Galaxy Ace phone (MDPI Again)and everything works OK.

However, I recently got hold of a new phone running KitKat.  However, it appears this handset is very low-spec.  (1GB storage, 249MB RAM).

Now, when I run my app on this handset, it uses the HDPI version of the resources (as mentioned above).  There are no errors, the app runs, but this particular resource simply displays as solid black.

**What have I tried?**

I though maybe it was a memory issue, so I used all manner of tools etc to reduce the file-size down to 182kb.  However, when I ran the app, I got the same issue.

So, I copied the LDPI image into the HDPI folder (which obviously has a lower pixel count) and it ran............... it displayed OK (file size larger than 182kb).

What is going on here? The physical resolution of the phone is 900 x 540.  Each individual image in the atlas is 960 x 459 so, with a bit of scaling this should fit fine as it does with other devices.

Another thing that confuses me is that my XHDPI folder contains an atlas in which each individual background is about 1/2 the width and height of the Nexus 10's screen, so this gets scaled up.  However, using Google's scaling laws ([Android: Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)), after scaling, each individual background image contained within the HDPI atlas is about the size of the screen of phone I'm using, so not much scaling required (whereas I would again, prefer to use images 1/2 the size of the screen).

Why is this phone not working with the current size file (physical size, not file-size) and is there any way to better manage or provide more alternate resources that just LDPI, MDPI, HDPI and XHDPI?

Comment: Your atlas texture is very wide, most (as far as I know) devices support max 4096 or 2048 sized textures.

Comment: Interesting @harism, I've not heard this before!  So, this atlas is an atlas of (near) full-screen background images.  Now, on my Nexus 10 which has a high res (2560 x 1600), my individual images in the atlas are 1310 * 612, so it scales up to fit the screen, now on my hdpi resources which this phone picks up, the resource is about the same size as this screen - without resizing it  (because I'm following Google's advise on this) how can I ensure than the resource this phone picks up is also about 1/2 size of the physical screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably exceeding the maximum texture size supported by the device. The width of your texture (5760) is very large. It's common for mobile devices to have texture size limits of 4096 or even 2048 in each dimension.

You can query the texture size limit with:

```
GLint maxSize = 0;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &maxSize);
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is more likely than the **power of 2** theory.  I just reduced the size of the bitmap and gave it a random size (3339 x 329), and it worked.  So you're probably right.  I didn't know about the upper size limit of some devices.  So the question would be, how do I then mitigate this?  If I reduce all of the textures (XHDPI, HDPI, MDPI and LDPI) then on some devices, it will be scaling up quite a lot (losing quality), any suggestion would be very welcome! Thank you @RetoKoradi

Comment: Not sure what your best strategy is. You could possibly check the maximum texture size at runtime like I showed in my answer, and downscale your bitmaps if they are larger than the texture size limit. That's of course not highly efficient to load a large bitmap only to downscale it immediately. Or you could have multiple versions in your resources/assets, and choose which one to load based on the texture size limit.

Comment: Thanks @RetoKoradi, I like the 2nd option there (providing multiple resources) but I've looked all over and can't find out how to do this (apart from X/H/M & LDPI - are there any articles you could point me to that would show me how to achieve this?  Thanks

Comment: OK so I basically reduced the size of the atlas in one direction and increased it in the other so now instead of 1 row of 6 backgrounds, I have 3 rows of 2 to keep the width low.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some of the  devices can load only **power of 2** ( 128 x 64, 512 x 512, 1024 x 512 etc) textures. Placing images in folders like hdpi,mdpi automatically scales down the image so there is no guarantee that image are always will be power of 2. Better approach would be place the images in `nodpi` folder. Or else you can put separate images in all the dp folders though but make sure that all are power of 2.

Comment: Interesting, I've been told that the 'power of 2' openGL limitation doesn't actually exist anymore.  The ones from my MDPI Folder which are 3840 x 306 *do* actually work!  I also don't think the no-dpi option is a go, my app needs to look as good as it can on all devices from the lowest spec handsets up to the latest tablets (an if I understand it correctly, using nodpi would mean providing only one set of resources?) - Is the power of 2 thing device specific?  I though it was a general OpenGL thing?  Cheers!

Comment: Yes..It is device specific and that issue still exists in some of the devices. I have experienced it many times. For example nexus 7 first generation 2012 model.

Comment: I thought mdpi, hdpi etc folders would be handy but you should disable inScaled flag when decoding image : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inScaled .

Comment: Wow @AbhishekV, I didn't know that! It's crazy to think that problem still exists! What I don't understand is that none of my textures are power of two, but it's only this on that is giving my problems :-(

Comment: @AbhishekV: Devices that can't load NPOT textures would not be ES 2.0 compliant. There are some restrictions on NPOT textures in ES 2.0, mainly that they can't be mipmapped, and that not all wrapping modes are available, unless the `GL_OES_texture_npot` is supported.